# How to select points within a specific time period in different data frames and then the distance between these two points based on lat/long

Tags: r, datetime, geospatial, distance

I would like to try and calculate the distance between animals at different times throughout the day. Data has been collected every `3` minutes.

I would like to get Animal `A` and compare it to Animal `B` and `C` first by finding the corresponding points for `B`, `C` and  that are closest IN TIME to `A` and then the metre distance between these

For example: (I made this up so might not be totally accurate)

```
Animal ID     timestamp           long       lat
a         2017-09-29 11:07:00 173.1975 -44.94617
a         2017-09-29 11:10:08 173.1976 -44.94619
a         2017-09-29 11:26:56 173.1976 -44.94629
b         2017-09-29 11:09:31 173.1975 -44.94620
b         2017-09-29 11:11:11 173.2345 -45.01769
c         2017-09-29 11:10:00 173.1975 -44.94617
c         2017-09-29 11:25:56 173.3790 -44.93702
```

In the above, for animal a, the first point at 11:07, neither `B` or `C` have a point within a minute of this = output `NA`.

Then, for the animal's point at `11:10:08`, both animal `b` and `c` have a point within a minute and I would like the metre distance between both these points and point a.

And so on.

Real data has approx `30` animals and over approx `2` weeks so something not too computationally heavy is a plus, though not imperative

**Desired output**

```
ref.animal    ref.timestamp     ref.long     ref.lat    animal1     animal1.timestamp      lag      animal1.long      animal1.lat     animal1.dist
a         2017-09-29 11:07:00   173.1975   -44.94617      b        2017-09-29 11:09:31     151       173.1975         -44.94620         5.43
a         2017-09-29 11:10:08   173.1976   -44.94619      b        2017-09-29 11:09:31     37        173.1975         -44.94620         10.88
a         2017-09-29 11:26:56   173.1976   -44.94629      b        2017-09-29 11:11:11     945       173.2345         -45.01769         21.80
```

Ultimately if I could make it a huge dataframe with all the animals listed as columns (e.g. animal.1; animal.2) this would be great but i'm happy to run it as seperate data frames for each animal pair.

lag = diff in seconds between two timestamps
dist = distance between two lat/long points

From here my goal will be to flag all scenarios where distance <5m, <10m, <20m etc and have a count of this

Comment: How should the output look like? (e.g. list, df, ... )

Comment: Desired output is a df with columns as follows
1. the ID of the animal being studied (animal A)
2. timestamp for A
3. ID of next animal (animal B)
4. timestamp for closest point IN TIME between animal B and animal A
5. distance (in metres) between the two points
6. ID of next animal (animal C)
and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you only want to get the distance between `a` and the other animals. Here is one possible solution when you want to get the distance between any pair of animals.

The algorithm works like this.

1. Spread the levels of `Animal ID` into columns.
2. Make a list containing each pair of `Animal ID` columns.
3. For each element of the list in 2, get an outer difference. (Get the difference of all possible pairs from each column).
4. Get the index of the difference that is less than 60 seconds.
5. Get the coordinates of the `Animal ID` corresponding to the index.
6. Get the difference in metres between the pairs of coordinates in 5.

### Caveat

I have only tried this for the case when two animals are within 60 seconds of each other only once, as in your data. But perhaps you can start with this. I can expand my answer if you can provide your desired output.

---

### The data

```
tt <- 'Animal ID,     timestamp,           long,       lat
a,         2017-09-29 11:07:00, 173.1975, -44.94617
a,         2017-09-29 11:10:08, 173.1976, -44.94619
a,         2017-09-29 11:26:56, 173.1976, -44.94629
b,         2017-09-29 11:09:31, 173.1975, -44.94620
b,         2017-09-29 11:11:11, 173.2345, -45.01769
c,         2017-09-29 11:10:00, 173.1975, -44.94617
c,         2017-09-29 11:25:56, 173.3790, -44.93702'


df <- read.table(text = tt, header = T, sep = ',')
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp)
```

### Spread the `Animal ID` into separate columns

```
df1 <- df %>% spread(Animal.ID, timestamp)
```

### Remove the long and lat columns

```
df2 <- df1[,c(-1,-2)]
```

### Make a list containing every possible pair of columns of `Animal ID`

```
df2_comb <- combn(colnames(df2), 2, function(x) list(cbind(df2[x[1]], df2[x[2]])))
```

### Steps 4-6

```
map_dfr(df2_comb, function(x) {index = which(abs(sapply(x[,1], 'difftime', x[,2], units = 'secs')) < 60, arr.ind = TRUE);
  point1 = c(df1$long[index[2]], df1$lat[index[2]]);
  point2 = c(df1$long[index[1]], df1$lat[index[1]]);
  names = paste(names(x), collapse = '-');
  dist = distm(point1, point2, fun=distVincentyEllipsoid);
  time1 = x[index[2],1];
  time2 = x[index[1],2];
  return(data.frame(names, time1, time2, dist))
})
```

### Output

```
  names               time1               time2  dist
1   a-b 2017-09-29 11:10:08 2017-09-29 11:09:31 7.970
2   a-c 2017-09-29 11:10:08 2017-09-29 11:10:00 8.199
3   b-c 2017-09-29 11:09:31 2017-09-29 11:10:00 3.334
```

- `names` correspond to the animal pair
- `time1` and `time2` correspond to the times in the rows in which each pair of animal is 60 seconds apart from each other.
- `dist` is the `distVincentyEllipsoid` (in `metres` I suppose).

Comment: Thanks @hpesoj626 this looks like it will be just about perfect for my needs or very close.. however, i just tried to run it now and got to Steps 4-6 and got NA values for time 1 and only the distance for the first GPS point?? 
 
there was also warning messages "in bind_rows(x, .id): unequal factor levels: coercing to character" and "in bind_rows(x, .id): binding character and factor vector: coercing into character vector"

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: edited my question to include desired output @hpesoj626 .... also note i've changed the requirement for the timestamps to be within 1minute to just flagging the closest timestamp in TIME